# Custom listener in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog

I have read if we want listener in dialog, we have to implement interface to our parent activity or fragment and use it as listener.
But what if we want to have custom listener ?

I don't want to make my parent activity/fragment bigger. I have read also we shouldn't use an injection via method for listener and we cannot use second constructor in our dialog.

So question is: How to create custom listener and inject it to dialog without expand parent (activity/fragment) ?

Answer (score 0):

*I hope I can help.*

I assume that you need customlistener that stored in another class.

first step if you need to have custom listener is creating interface class, and put some fun or method inside.

this website will explain how to create custom listener, even though it's wrote in java, you will easily implement if you understand the concept

> > [Create custom listener](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners)<<